# How do I make a character controller in swift using touch?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I want to make a simple platformer game in Xcode using Swift so that when I hold the left side of the screen, it continuously moves left until let go and vice versa. I have already added a jump feature but if you have any other suggestions I am open to take advice.

Here is my GameController.swift code:
   import SpriteKit

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
let character = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"square.png")
let block = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "square.png")
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */
    //Physics
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0, -5.0)
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
    //Character
    character.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),   
y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    character.setScale(0.25)
    character.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: character.size)
        self.addChild(character)

        //block

        block.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:  
        CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)*0.3)
        block.setScale(0.2)
        block.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: block.size)
        block.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        self.addChild(block)


}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
   /* Called when a touch begins */
    for touch:AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if location.x < CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) && location.y <    
    CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)*0.7{
            character.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: -50, dy: 0))
        } else if location.x > CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) && location.y <           
    CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)*0.7{
            character.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 50, dy: 0))
        } else if location.y > character.position.y + 15  {
            character.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 50))
        }





        func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

        }
func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
                }
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Just have it so that when the touch location in `touchesBegan` is on the left side of the screen (for example), begin an SKAction that runs forever moving the character to the left until the touch is released––in `touchesEnded`, remove that SKAction. The same applies to the right half of the screen, etc. Makes sense or do you want me to post a full answer?––this is what you're asking, right?

Comment: Is there any specific reason that you're using `.applyImpulse` on the `physicsBody` instead of adding an `SKAction`?

Comment: I don't know what else to use is my only reason really...

Comment: Could you possibly post a full answer please? I have been struggling with this for months. Thanks

Comment: Sure, I'm typing up an answer now :)

Comment: Thanks again for the help

Comment: Do you want `character` to be able to move in only one direction at a time (not diagonally)?

Comment: No he can also move diagonally

Comment: I think this is what I was going for. I can't test it currently but I will in a few hours. Thanks

Comment: Currently, the character cannot move diagonally. This means that only one button can be pressed at a time. Would you like me to add that functionality?

Comment: Yes, that would help a lot

Comment: Instead of diagonally can you improve the jump functionality

Comment: What do you want it to do?

Comment: Just jump higher and fall down faster

Comment: To make it jump higher, simply change **either** the duration **or** the displacement. For example, change the displacement to 50 instead of 20. Now, it has to move 50px in 0.1 seconds. This gives it a greater velocity. A greater velocity means more time needed by gravity to make the velocity 0 and then come back down. That in turn means that it travels farther up. Makes sense? Also, adding diagonal functionality is very simple. It's basically copying and pasting what you have in `touchesBegan` and removing SKActions instead of adding them.

Comment: Ok last question, how do I make it instantly stop moving when the touch is let go instead of sliding and slowing down?

Comment: It doesn't slide and slow down...

Comment: Ok then thanks for everything

Comment: If my answer answers your question fully, then can you please accept it? If it doesn't answer your question fully, then please, tell me and I'll add/edit.

Comment: I know this is off topic but I want the game to only work in landscape mode but when I rotate the simulator it cuts off the part where the character is? How do I fix

Comment: Go to the build settings and uncheck Portrait

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    character.removeActionForKey("moveAction")
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch:AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if location.x < CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) && location.y < CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)*0.7{
            moveAction = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.moveByX(-20, y: 0, duration: 0.1))
            let character.runAction(moveAction, withKey: "moveAction")
        } else if location.x > CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) && location.y < CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)*0.7{
            let moveAction = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.moveByX(20, y: 0, duration: 0.1))
            character.runAction(moveAction, withKey: "moveAction")
        } else if location.y > character.position.y + 15  {
            let moveAction = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.moveByX(0, y: 20, duration: 0.1))
            character.runAction(moveAction, withKey: "moveAction")
        }
    }
}
```

I edited the `touchesBegan` method and I added a `touchesEnded` method. You seem to have tried to *embed* `touchesEnded` (and `update`) into the `touchesBegan`, which you definitely cannot do.

Okay, so, the code is pretty self explanatory, but anyway:

Instead of what you had with the vectors, I added an SKAction that runs forever. Changing the duration will change how fast the object moves. A lower duration results in a faster object, and vice versa (because lower duration means less time to get somewhere, hence a faster speed). When `touchesEnded` is called, the action, whose key is `"moveAction"` is removed from `character`, thereby stopping it.

That's pretty much it. If you have any questions, please, tell me!

By the way, I'm not sure if you intended for this, but when you run the action for the object to move up, `character` ultimately ends up bouncing up and down because of the gravity.